# Swing editor for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using **Eclipse** and searching for an **Swing editor tool** for Eclipse. I found **jigloo** plugin for eclipse. But its not free for commercial purpose.

Can anyone suggest some good swing editor tools for eclipse (which must be a free for commercial purpose)?

Thanks,
Bala Krishnan.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Window Builder (Eclipse Indigo):
https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Comment: Hi,Thanks..... I like Window Builder tool. But is there any plugin for this? I am using eclipse Helios. I found we can install it through eclipse under, Help --> Install new software. But is there any plugin available for download... So that we can put them directly under eclipse - plugin directory and start using it..

Comment: Help>Install new software is the recommended way of installing any plugin, because with that you get a dependency check whether anything else has to be installed first. However, there are some instructions on how to use an archived update site here: https://code.google.com/intl/de/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks.. I need to clarify few things. I have downloaded com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.3.6.update.site_2.3.3.zip and I think this will install all Google Plugins (Not sure).. But I need the plugins and features only available for Window Builder. How can I do that or is there any link which suggests the files to be used for Window Builder alone? Thanks again..

Comment: Yes, it contains all plugins but you can select which plugins you want during the installation process, so if you just select the ones regarding WindowBuilder, you should be fine.